# add OnClick event on a div

Tags: javascript, html, events, eventhandler

I'm trying to add an event of a button that is in a div.

HTML :

```
<template id="modele-panier" type="text/AhuntsicModele">
  <div class="dialog-item">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src={cheminImage} alt="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <h2>Article : {libelleProduit}</h2>
          <p>Qte : {qteProduit} prix : {prixProduit}$</p>
        </td>  
        <div class="supp">
          <td>
            <a href="#" id="{libelleProduit}">Supprimer </a>
          </td>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Controler.js

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches('button')) {
    controleur.ajouterPanier(e.target.id);
  } else if (e.target && e.target.matches('#main')) {
    controleur.loadCatalogue();
  } else if (e.target && e.target.matches('#getBMW')) {
    controleur.loadBMW();
  } else if (e.target && e.target.matches('#getAudi')) {
    controleur.loadAudi();
  } else if (e.target && e.target.matches('#getMercedes')) {
    controleur.loadMercedes();
  } else if (e.target && e.target.matches('#icone_compte')) {
    controleur.creationCompte();
  }  // THIS EVENT RIGHT HERE :
  else if (event.target.matches('supp')) { 
    alert(e.target.id)
    controleur.supprimerItem();
  }
});
```

Im not able to add the event to the div class supp all the other are working fine since im not using a div class for the other ones.
Thanks

Comment: `event` is not defined, as you refer to it as `e` in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this

```
const div = document.getElementsByClassName("supp");

  else if (div[0]!=undefined) { 
    alert(e.target.id)
    controleur.supprimerItem();
  }
```

hope it helps

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH THIS WORKED
Edit : this worked but the (div[0]!=undefined) now affects all my page its trying to aply this method on all tthings i click

Comment: well what this does is it finds the div class name `supp` and if the class exists add the listerner event to it, i.e it does this no matter where you click in document.

looking at your code, you want  this to happen only of the exact div is clicked you can do

`e.target.className.contains("supp")`  in the if part to make it work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like your controller logic to detect and process click events on the element with the `supp` class.

To achieve that with minimal changes to your code, you could do the following via the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) interface:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  /* Existing code removed for bervity */
  
  /* Use classList.contains method to check if target element has supp class */
  if (event.target.classList.contains('supp')) {
    alert(e.target.id)
    controleur.supprimerItem();
  }

});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></td>
    <td>
      <h2>Article : {libelleProduit}</h2>
      <p>Qte : {qteProduit} prix : {prixProduit}$</p>
    </td>
    <div class="supp">
      <td><a href="#" id="foo">Supprimer </a></td>
    </div>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I'm assuming that the click handler is targeting elements that are dynamically added to the DOM (which is why you're running the if/else if check inside of the click handler?) - another approach to this logic that might give you a bit more flexibility would be to query the DOM via a CSS-like selector and the [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  /* Existing code removed for bervity */
  
  /* Query document during click for first .supp relative to table */
  const suppDiv = document.querySelector("table .supp")
  if(suppDiv) {
    alert('clicked .supp')
  }

});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></td>
    <td>
      <h2>Article : {libelleProduit}</h2>
      <p>Qte : {qteProduit} prix : {prixProduit}$</p>
    </td>
    <div class="supp">
      <td><a href="#" id="foo">Supprimer </a></td>
    </div>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: exactly what im trying to do but im not able to put a event handler on that div
I tried your classList but it didnt work too
Thanks still

Comment: That's odd - just updated answer with a second approach that involves `querySelector()`. Does that help/make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a function parameter `event`, which isn't called in your function. You named the parameter `e` in your function.

Also, [`.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) checks if an element would normally be targeted based on a selector string. Which is what you would normally use to target elements with [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). So `supp` should be changed to `.supp`.

So your code should work when you change it to:

```
} else if (e.target.matches('.supp')) { 
  controleur.supprimerItem();
}
```

Or even:

```
} else if (e.target && e.target.matches('.supp')) { 
  controleur.supprimerItem();
}
```

Like the rest of your if-statements.

Here is a snippet to show that this code should work as intended:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches(".supp")) {
    alert("It works");
  }
});
```

```css
.supp {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="supp">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `alert('It works');` after the if-statement. I think the `controleur.supprimerItem()` doesn't work then. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Please check my code snippet for a proof of concept @Anasde.